# does not have class type

Tags: c++, class

Trying to iterate through a vector in a class in C++ using:

```
for(vector<Album>::iterator it = a.getAlbumList.begin(); it != a.getAlbumList.end(); it++)
```

yet it gives me the error:

> error: 'a.AlbumCollection::getAlbumList' does not have class type

This is frustrating me as I have no idea what this means, and I have tried to follow other suggestions but to no help. I'm only just a beginner, so if some one could explain this to me simply that would be great thanks.

Here is the class:
.cpp: http://pastebin.com/MSCcHjXb
.h: http://pastebin.com/Xq4nqSan

Comment: `getAlbumList()` is a function.

Comment: I know this, hence the increasing amount of cunfusion.

Comment: not related to this solution, but start using ++it instead of it++

Comment: There's probably many things I could do better, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You (apparently) want to *call* the `getAlbumList` member function, so your code should be:

```
for(vector<Album>::iterator it = a.getAlbumList().begin(); 
                            it != a.getAlbumList().end(); 
                            it++)
```